# Facebook Comments Plugin AJAX callback for post success

Tags: post, callback, facebook-comments

I'm using [Facebook's Comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) plugin.

I would like to trigger a custom JS function after a user successfully posts from my site.

Is there a callback / function / method to accomplish this? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395789/fb-comments-events-comment-create-and-comment-remove-not-working), the following works, hope it helps someone

```
//INCLUDE THE SCRIPT FIRST
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={YOURAPPID}";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


//INITIALIZE THE OBJECTS
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId:  '{YOURAPPID}',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml:  true,
        oauth: true
    });

    //AND THOSE WILL FIRE THE EVENTS :)

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
        function (response) {
            console.log('create', response);
        });
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove',
        function (response) {
           console.log('remove', response);
        });

};
```